# How to get Solr field type

Tags: java, solr

Is there any way of getting the metadata for a solr core ?

For instance I know the core name, and can obtain a SolServer from that and I also know the field name.

Is there any way to determine the metadata though. Specifically I would like to know whether the field type is an int or a double.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a request to the luke request handler:

http://localhost:8983/solr/corename/admin/luke?show=schema&wt=json&_=1453816769771

The output will include the schema for the core, along with the defined fields, their settings and their types:

```
{"fields":{"xyz":{"type":"string","flags":"I-S-M---OF-----l","copyDests":[],"copySources":[]}, .... }
```

A neat trick to find these endpoints is to watch the 'network' tab when browsing the admin interface to Solr, as the admin interface is just a static HTML / Javascript frontend that makes all the requests for actual content from the Solr server behind the scenes.

Comment: Yes spot on, also I found a LukeRequest object in the API which I utlimately passed as a request to my SolrServer object and traversed the tree that way.